# MNIST with fewer pixels?

Tags: mnist

MNIST images are 28x28 pixels. Perhaps a silly question: is there anything like MNIST, but whose images have fewer pixels?

Comment: You could just down-sample the MNIST images, no?

Comment: Hello. Welcome to AI SE. It's not clear **why** you're asking this question. Please, edit your post to clarify that. Moreover, questions asking for datasets are generally off-topic here.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sklearn has [digit dataset](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_digits.html) with images of size $8 \times 8$:

```
Classes
10
Samples per class
~180
Samples total
1797
Dimensionality
64
Features
integers 0-16
```